# Existe Data Annotation que evita duplicidade de dados no Banco?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, dataannotations

Como faço para evitar que dados sejam duplicados no banco usando Data Annotation ou seria através de outra validação?

Comment: Você quer criar uma **Unique Key** via *data annotation*, certo?

Comment: sim, por exemplo, e-mail único, produto único etc...

Comment: A resposta do Eduardo já resolve.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @FabioSouza Está usando EF? Que versão?

Comment: @bigown desculpa a ignorância, mas o que seria EF? Entity Framework? se for é a versão 6

Comment: @FabioSouza, respondendo sua pergunta acima, EF, e abreviatura para Entity Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é com `RemoteValidation`, funciona assim: você deverá criar uma `ActionResult` que retorne um `JsonResult` com `true` or `false` indicando se a validação passou. Essa validação será feita por Ajax se usar a Unobtrusive Validation.

Isso não é um tipo da validação que irá criar um índice no banco de dados, o que lançaria uma exceção ao tentar salvar o dado duplicado. O índice te garante integridade, com certeza, mas essa solução é mais amigável ao usuário não sendo necessário tratar o fluxo da exceção. Use as duas soluções se for o caso.

No model:

```
// primeiro parametro é nome da ação, o segundo do controller
[Remote("ValidarEmailUnico", "Usuario", ErrorMessage = "E-mail já cadastrado")]
public string Email{ get; set; }
```

UsuarioController:

```
 public ActionResult ValidarEmailUnico(string Email)
 {
    var emailDisponivel = contexto.Usuarios.Where(u => u.Email == Email).Count() == 0;
    return Json(emailDisponivel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Mais aqui: http://www.macoratti.net/15/02/aspn_vremt1.htm

Comment: `var emailDisponivel = contexto.Usuarios.Any(u => u.Email == Email);`  Assim ficar melhor  e mais performática.

Comment: No caso teria que inverter o retorno, pois Any irá retornar true se houver e-mail cadastrado.

Comment: isso, dessa forma é melhor, mas ele ainda teria que passar o parâmetro chave da tabela ...

Answer (score 5):

```
public class User
{       
   [Index(IsUnique=true)]
   public string UserName{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: com isto ele já verifica no banco se já tem a informação cadastrado?

Comment: o [Index(..)]  não é reconhecido pelo sistema, me da essa mensagem: **the type or namespace name 'Index' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** e se eu clico **CTRL+ponto** ele pede pra gerar uma classe...

Comment: com isso ele vai criar um campo que não vai poder ter valores iguais. se você quer verificar vai ter que customizar seu data annotation.

Answer (score 3):

Tem algumas formas, a que provavelmente é a mais adequada para você seria usar o atributo `Index` para criar um índice no banco de dados e indicar que ele deve ter chave única.

```
public class SuaClasse {       
   [Index("NomeDoIndice", IsUnique = true)]
   public string ColunaUnica { get; set; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/Unique.cs).

É possível montar o índice com várias colunas.

Não esqueça de adicionar o *namespace* `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` para poder usar esse atributo.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Comment: o que seria o "NomeDoIndice"?

Comment: Seria o nome que quer dar ao índice dentro do banco de dados. Ele tem que ter um nome. È como se estivesse escrevendo isso no banco de dados. è como estivesse usando um `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Hum talvez seja por isso que ele estivesse dando erro ao executar meu sistema dizendo que minha tabela já existia... sabe o que eu poderia estar fazendo de errado ? Já tentei com o nome igual ao campo, nome diferente e até sem nome, mas dava sempre a mesma msg.

Comment: Aí o problema parece ser outro completamente diferente do que está na pergunta.

Comment: Este erro só aparece se estiver usando este annotation

Comment: Depois eu edito a pergunta mostrando o que eu fiz e o erro que da.

Comment: É, isso é normal, se você tira algo que está dando erro realmente ele não aparece, mas não é o que deseja. Não deve editar a pergunta, se tem outro problema, deve ser outra pergunta. Essa parece ter sido resolvida. Veja o [tour].